# Simple polymorphism in C#

Tags: c#, methods, polymorphism

This program is about polymorphism in C#. But call method does not working in visual studio. The program give error like "The name 'Call' does not exist in the current context".

```
class dog
{
}
class cat
{
}
class process
{
    static void Call(dog d)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("dog is called");
    }
    static void Call(cat c)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("cat is called");
    }
}
class polymorphism
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        dog dog = new dog();
        cat cat = new cat();
        Call(dog);
    }

}
```

Comment: Move `Call` method into your `polymorphism` class or use `process.Call` instead. It has nothing to do with polymorphism, though.

Comment: Your definition of polymorphism and mine are very different it seems...

Comment: @DavidG funnily enough the answers are upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class process
{
    public static void Call(dog d) //2
    {
        Console.WriteLine("dog is called");
    }
    public static void Call(cat c) //3
    {
        Console.WriteLine("cat is called");
    }
}
class polymorphism
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        dog dog = new dog();
        cat cat = new cat();
        process.Call(dog); //1
    }
}
```

**What changes I've done?**

1. process has `Call`, not `polymorphism`. So, call `Call` by referring `process`.
2. and 3. You cannot access a method outside class if you haven't defined an access level. So, I added `public` as we need to access `Call` outside the `process` class.

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 3):

You have to tell from which class is the static method coming from - that is `process.Call(dog);`. That should make it work

Comment: Don't forget to make the static methods public. Another way would be to make `polymorphism` inherit from `process`

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your program:

1. You are not working with functions, but with methods. That means when younare not within `process`,  you can not invoke `Call` without specifying the class.
2. The `Call` methods have no explicit visibility, that means they are `private` by default and as such not callable outside `process`.
3. There is nothing polymorphic in your program (not even `cat` and `dog`).  What you are doing is to verify that overloading works. Overloading is no object oriented concept. It's syntactic sugar. On top of everything, your methods are `static`. There is no polymorphism with static methods.

Your issued 1 and 2 are resolved like this:

```
class process
{
    public static void Call(dog d)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("dog is called");
    }
    public static void Call(cat c)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("cat is called");
    }
}
class polymorphism
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        dog dog = new dog();
        cat cat = new cat();
        process.Call(dog);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var dog = new Dog();
            var cat = new Cat();
            var whale = new Whale();

            var c = new Caller();

            c.CallFeature(dog);
            c.CallFeature(cat);
            c.CallFeature(whale);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Cat : Animal
    {
        public override string Feature()
        {
            return "sharp claws";
        }
    }

    class Dog : Animal
    {
        public override string Feature()
        {
            return "big teeth";
        }
    }

    class Whale : Animal
    {

    }

    class Animal
    {
        public virtual string Feature()
        {
            return "unknown features";
        }
    }

    class Caller
    {
        public void CallFeature(Animal a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("a {0} has {1}", a.GetType().Name, a.Feature());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```css
    //polymorphism
    class dog
    {
        
    }
    class cat
    {
    }
    class process
    {
        static void Call(dog d)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("dog is called");
        }
        static void Call(cat c)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("cat is called");
        }
    
        public static void Main()
        {
            dog dog = new dog();
            cat cat = new cat();
            Call(dog);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Akshay, what're you doing?